# Magento 2 - How to call REST API to register a new customer

Tags: magento2, customer, api

In Magento2, How to call REST API to register a new customer (What APIs need to call step by step). Thanks!

Comment: better you create your own rest API for registration as default API will ask so much data..

Answer (score 7):

Refer below link for Magento 2.x version. http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/

I have used below body for creating customers through Rest Api and it worked properly.

Url : http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/rest/V1/customers

Type: POST

Content-Type : application/json

payload Data:

```
  {
     "customer": {
         "email": "abc@gmail.com",
         "firstname": "Abc",
         "lastname": "Xyz"   

     },
     "password": "Abc@123456"
  }
```

Response:

```
 {
    "id": 4,
    "group_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-01-27 18:35:48",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-27 18:35:48",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "Abc",
    "lastname": "Xyz",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0
}
```

Call through postman see example in attachment:

[image: Register customer using Magento2 rest api]

Answer (score 0):

We can use **/rest/V1/customers**: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#resource_customerAccountManagementV1

For example, payload:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "group_id": 0,
  "default_billing": "string",
  "default_shipping": "string",
  "confirmation": "string",
  "created_at": "string",
  "updated_at": "string",
  "created_in": "string",
  "dob": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "middlename": "string",
  "prefix": "string",
  "suffix": "string",
  "gender": 0,
  "store_id": 0,
  "taxvat": "string",
  "website_id": 0,
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "customer_id": 0,
      "region": {
        "region_code": "string",
        "region": "string",
        "region_id": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "region_id": 0,
      "country_id": "string",
      "street": [
        "string"
      ],
      "company": "string",
      "telephone": "string",
      "fax": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "firstname": "string",
      "lastname": "string",
      "middlename": "string",
      "prefix": "string",
      "suffix": "string",
      "vat_id": "string",
      "default_shipping": true,
      "default_billing": true,
      "extension_attributes": {},
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

**Url : http://www.test.com/rest/V1/customers**

**Type: POST**

**Content-Type : application/json**

**Body Raw Json Data:-**

```
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "Test",
        "lastname": "User"   

    },
    "password": "Front@12345"
}
```

***To block Api user creation add below line at robots.txt***

*Rest Api block if no need*

Disallow:rest/default/V1/customers

Disallow:rest/V1/customers